# Links not working in drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I'm using using a dropdown menu for a magento-website, when the width is below 1024px.
The drop down works fine, however when the menu is shown (By the `.fadeToggle();` method) The links wont work, instead it hides the `ul`, as if I had pressed the link again.
As far as I can see, the button that triggers the effect ( `#nav li.level0 a`) doesn't cover the links in the drop-down menu. So I can't see why it acts like I am clicking it. Can't find anything weird with the css either.

Tried it in a jsfiddle, and here it works, so maybe it is css related?

JS-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpVZ9/

Here's a link to the website: http://shop.veivecouture.com/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav" class="default">

    <li class="level0 parent">
<a href="http://shop.veivecouture.com/collections.html">
            <span>Collections <em>+</em></span>
    </a>
        <ul class="level1" style="top: 83px; display none">
            <li class="level1">
                <a href="http://shop.veivecouture.com/collections/tensione-superficiale.html" class=""><span>Head</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav{
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav a{
padding: 0px;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav span{
padding-left: 20px;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav li.level0{
width: 45%;
max-width: 45%;
border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd; 
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav span.plus{
right: -10px;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav ul.level1 {
width: 100%;
top: 100px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
display: block;
pointer-events: none;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav ul.level1 li{
width: 100%;
top: 100px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
top: 36px;
left: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
pointer-events: none;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav ul.level1 li a{
pointer-events: auto;
}

.header-sidebar .box-scroll .nav-container #nav li:first-child{
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Here's my JS:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 1024) {
            $('#nav li.parent ul li.level1').hide();
        $('#nav li.level0 a').click(function(e){ return false;});
        $('#nav li.level0 a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).parent('li').find('ul li.level1').stop().fadeToggle(500);
                    $('#nav li.level0 a').not(this).parent('li').find('.level1:visible').hide();
        });
        }
```

Comment: why are you binding two click handlers for the same element..?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML and CSS?

Comment: You mean the 'return false' bind?

Comment: Just took a look at your site. With a width < 1024, looking at console when I clicked on Body -> Ear, this error came up `Uncaught TypeError: Object http://shop.veivecouture.com/body-parts/ear.html has no method 'attr' `. So that might be why it's not doing anything.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. I wonder what is interrupting it then?
The thing is, when I hover over the links in Chrome, I can see the link url displayed in the bottom left corner. So I wonder what is interfering...

Comment: Just before the `window.location = $(this).attr('href');`, try to use `console.log($(this))` and see what you get. If you get the only the link, try `window.location = $(this)`

Comment: Thanks, I now that part of the code wasn't clean either, however I figured out what the main problem was (se my own answer below). Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the propagation of the click event up to the `level1` ul. (you have them nested and when you click the link the action goes up to the parent elements and it also triggers the "hide the menu" action)

This code should do the trick, if I managed to get your HTML structure right.

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 1024) {
     jQuery('#nav .level1 a').click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
     });
}
```

Please check it out as it's hard for me to test it out atm, or provide a Jsfiddle if it's not working so we can tinker with the code

Comment: It's wierd, I tried it out in JS-fiddle, and there it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bpVZ9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was that it was targeting all the `<a>`s within the `li.level0`, even those within `li.level1`, so therefore I had to put in an exclusion (`.not('ul li.level1 a')`in the JS as such:

```
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1024) {
        jQuery('#nav li.parent ul li.level1').hide();
        jQuery('#nav li.parent a').not('ul li.level1 a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).find('span.plus').toggleClass('opened');
    jQuery('#nav li.level0 a').not(this).parent('li').find('.level1:visible').hide();
                jQuery(this).parent('li').find('ul li.level1').stop().fadeToggle(500);
        });
    }
```